# jQuery append not adding Metadata in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, cross-browser, append, meta-tags

This problem is specific to Firefox. It works fine in Opera and Chrome (I didn't check in any other browsers).

**Problem:** Please check this [Link](http://wplegion.com). When you click on the Download button, a pop-up option form appears. When you fill it up and hit Submit, the text in the pop up changes, and the download begins (in other browsers), but in Firefox the download doesn't begin.

I am using this code in jquery function to make the download start:

```
$('.downloadMeta').append("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=http://linktofile.url' />");
```

I have even tried this, but it also didn't work in Firefox, and worked fine in other browsers:

```
$(document.head).append("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=http://linktofile.url' />");$
```

Comment: There is no reason to perform a redirect like this. Use `setTimeout(func, duration)`. Besides that, if you need a solution ASAP, pay someone for it. By the way, people will put trash email address or just gibberish in that field - having to enter an email address to download something is rather annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just set `window.location.href` to the right URL after a delay of 1 second instead? That should work across browsers better.

e.g.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://linktofile.url';
}, 1000);
```